# Web Compiler: JavaScript file > 100KB minification error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, web-essentials, web-compiler

I'm having a hard time finding out what options are available for different file types with Mads Kristensen's [Web Compiler](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler) extension. Am I missing a list somewhere? We're having an issue with this error coming up:

> The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "index.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".

when we try to minify a larger JavaScript file. It seems to be due to an issue with Babel, which I'm assuming the Web Compiler is using, but I was hoping for a comprehensive list of options for issues in the future as well.

Comment: I have same issue, any work around?

Comment: We're transitioning over more to Gulp now that the front end is changing so much with Visual Studio (and NPM/Bower). The files we were having this issue with are external libraries and don't need to be compiled often so we just did it manually outside of VS.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround for visual studio is change compilerconfig.json and add "minify": {     "enabled": false    }
For example:

```
    {
    "outputFile": "Scripts/index.es5.js",
    "inputFile": "Scripts/index.js",
    "minify": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  }
```